# How to append json from php to a listview?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, jquery-mobile

I loaded a json fuction from a php page and I append it to an UL, Which creates a list.When I delete a row, I reuse the same function to re-append the list; it works, but sometime I have to click twice before it removes theselected row.

Is there a way to simplify this process as i am new to jquery?

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#two', function () {
    var url="http://localhost/budget/items_list.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(result){
    console.log(result);
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        var budgeted_id=field.budgeted_id;
        var name=field.name;
        var budget_amount=field.budget_amount;
        var trans_amount=field.trans_amount;
        var balance=field.balance;
        $("#listview").append('<li  data-icon="delete"><a href="#">'+name+'<span class="ui-li-count">Bal: $'+balance+'</span></a><a class="del" id="'+budgeted_id+'" href="#"></a></li>').listview("refresh");
    });
}); 

$(document).on("click",'.del',function(){ 
    $("#listview").empty();      
    budgeted_id = (this.id);
    $.post('delete_item.php',{postbudgeted_id:budgeted_id});
    var url="http://localhost/budget/items_list.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
           var budgeted_id=field.budgeted_id;
           var name=field.name;
           var budget_amount=field.budget_amount;
           var trans_amount=field.trans_amount;
           var balance=field.balance;
           $("#listview").append('<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#">'+name+'<span class="ui-li-count">Bal: $'+balance+'</span></a><a class="del" id="'+budgeted_id+'" href="#"></a></li>').listview("refresh");
        }) 
    }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it isn't a bad idea to reuse the same function, you will be sure to get always the actual data you have on server-side.

From your description of the issue, I believe you just only need to chain the two ajax calls.

Here an example how to do that, adapted on the fly from [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
function createList(result){
  $.each(result, function(i, field){
    var budgeted_id=field.budgeted_id;
    var name=field.name;
    var budget_amount=field.budget_amount;
    var trans_amount=field.trans_amount;
    var balance=field.balance;
    $("#listview").empty().append('<li  data-icon="delete"><a href="#">'+name+'<span class="ui-li-count">Bal: $'+balance+'</span></a><a class="del" id="'+budgeted_id+'" href="#"></a></li>').listview("refresh");
  });
}

function getListData(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/budget/items_list.php",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
      createList(result);
    }
  });
}

$(document).on("pageinit", "#two", function () {
  getListData();
}); 

$(document).on("click", ".del",function(){  
  var budgeted_id = (this.id);
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "delete_item.php"
    method: "POST",
    data: {postbudgeted_id:budgeted_id}
  });
  var chained = request.then(function() {
    getListData();
  });
});
```

Please, note this is untested, but you got the idea. If there is an ajax error, your list will remain untouched, up to you to trap these errors and display in your web page a toaster notification.

If chaining the ajax calls won't work, maybe you should investigate your backend.