# Error message Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to populate my jquery mobile listview using ajax to get my list of movie titles by doing a php Mysql query with data in json.
I successfully obtained the data in the correct json format, however in my javascript I get the error on line.... li.appendChild("a")

```
HTML 
<div data-role="main"  class="ui-content">
         <ul data-role="listview" id="list" >
         </ul >
</div>
```

```
getcatagories2_mobile.php

<?php

include("includes/connection.php");

$q="Comedy";

$resultActor = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,title, plot,catagory,release_date,rated FROM ".TBL_DATA." WHERE catagory LIKE '%".$q."%' ORDER BY title  ");    

$x= array();

    while($rowMovie = mysqli_fetch_array($resultActor)) {
        $x[]= array("Category" => $rowMovie['title']);

        }
       $jsonarray=json_encode($x);
       echo $jsonarray;

?>
```

```
successful sample JSON format output

[{"Category":"22 Jump Street"},{"Category":"27 Dresses"}]
```

```
my called javascript function using ajax...

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("GET", "getcatagories2_mobile.php", true); 

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
                {
                  var list = document.getElementById("list");
                  var data= xhr.responseText;
                  var vec= JSON.parse(data);
                        vec.forEach(
                              function(ob)
                              {
                                  var li = document.createElement("li");
                                  var a = document.createElement("a");
                                  var text = document.createTextNode("ob.Category");
                                  a.appendChild(text);
                                  a.setAttribute("href","#");
                                  li.appendChild("a");
                                  list.appendChild("li");

                              }
                         ); 
            $('#list').listview('refresh');  

            }
         }
                      xhr.send();


    };
```

when I used google debug I get my error on line->  li.appendChild("a"), when I hover over  var vec= JSON.parse(data), the data is shown correctly.

what I am trying to achieve is simply for my jquery mobile to execute as such

```
<div data-role="main"  class="ui-content">
         <ul data-role="listview" id="list" >

            <li><a href="#">22 Jump Street</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">27 Dresses</a></li>

         </ul >
</div>
```

Comment: You will go a lot faster by appending to the DOM outside the loop. Just concatenate your list items as text and then do something like  `$('#list').append(html).listview('refresh');` in one shot.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I don't understand "appending to the DOM outside the loop. Just concatenate your list items as text " Im not an expert :(

Comment: no worries... just give a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44964848/4845566 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915438/4845566

Comment: ok I will try to figure this out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the quotes from your appendChild-calls, otherwise you pass a string to that function and it does not know how to handle that. Wihtout the quotes you pass the object-reference to the function.

```
li.appendChild(a);
list.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: great , I had to do the same as you suggested  to remove quotes on  "ob.Category". I do get the list now, except Im not getting that jquerymobile style list, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Yeah, you're missing the knowledge that anything in quotes is a String.

Comment: my list doesnt look the style of Jquery mobile...like this one http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/listview/